# Create numbers within an array that add up to a set amount

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fairly new to PHP - programming in general. So basically what I need to accomplish is, create an array of *x* amount of numbers (created randomly) whose value add up to *n*:

Let's say, I have to create 4 numbers that add up to 30. I just need the first random dataset. The 4 and 30 here are variables which will be set by the user.

Essentially something like

```
x = amount of numbers;
n = sum of all x's combined;

// create x random numbers which all add up to n;

$row = array(5, 7, 10, 8) // these add up to 30
```

Also, no duplicates are allowed and all numbers have to be positive integers.

I need the values within an array. I have been messing around with it sometime, however, my knowledge is fairly limited. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *(related)* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Thats extremely helpful.

Comment: @RussellDias, Do the numbers all have to be non-negative?

Comment: Yes. I'll add that to my original post too. Sorry for lack of info.

Comment: What should happen in the case of x=3, n=4? Also, you may want to look at http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Integer-Partition-0.03/Partition.pm, you can probably port that perl code over to PHP. Alternatively, you could read the paper cited there for the algorithm.

Comment: What range of n, x are you interested in?

Comment: n can be any positive integer > 1. x would end up being: n(n+1)/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, this is a really cool problem. I'm almost sure that my approach doesn't even distribute the numbers perfectly, but it should be better than some of the other approaches here.

I decided to build the array from the lowest number up (and shuffle them at the end). This allows me to always choose a random range that will allows yield valid results. Since the numbers must always be increasing, I solved for the highest possible number that ensures that a valid solution still exists (ie, if n=4 and max=31, if the first number was picked to be 7, then it wouldn't be possible to pick numbers greater than 7 such that the sum of 4 numbers would be equal to 31).

```
$n = 4;
$max = 31;
$array = array();

$current_min = 1;
while( $n > 1 ) {
    //solve for the highest possible number that would allow for $n many random numbers
    $current_max = floor( ($max/$n) - (($n-1)/2) );
    if( $current_max < $current_min ) throw new Exception( "Can't use combination" );
    $new_rand = rand( $current_min, $current_max ); //get a new rand
    $max -= $new_rand; //drop the max
    $current_min = $new_rand + 1; //bump up the new min
    $n--; //drop the n
    $array[] = $new_rand; //add rand to array
}
$array[] = $max; //we know what the last element must be
shuffle( $array );
```

EDIT: For large values of `$n` you'll end up with a lot of grouped values towards the end of the array, since there is a good chance you will get a random value near the max value forcing the rest to be very close together. A possible fix is to have a weighted rand, but that's beyond me.

Comment: THanks mate :) I just made a few minor tweaks and it works like a charm :)

Comment: I think you know this is does not generate a completely random series, otherwise there would be no need for the shuffle at the end ;)
There sure is alot of randomness there, but creating rands in reaction to previous rands and totals can introduce tendencies -lumps in the distribution- which may manifest in certain tests and applications.

Comment: @strainer As I mentioned in the "EDIT" when the $n value gets large, the values seem to clump up near the end. This could probably be solved by a weighted rand. This is a very tricky issue to solve without the clumping problem.

Comment: @Kendall you might be interested in the solution posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794582/replace-duplicate-values-in-array-with-new-randomly-generated-values

Comment: @RussellDias I came to somewhat the same conclusion as cletus, that was the main reason I asked which range of n, x. If the number of combinations is low enough, brute force calculation is possible. This solution is a bit more practical, but by no means perfect :P

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for helping me out mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood you correctly, but try this:

```
$n = 4;
$max = 30;
$array = array();

do {
    $random = mt_rand(0, $max);

    if (!in_array($random, $array)) {
        $array[] = $random;
        $n--;
    }
} while (n > 0);
```

Comment: I need four numbers that add to the $max variable you have used. Like the example I have used above: array(5, 7, 10, 8) // these add up to 30 
Sorry for being unclear mate.

Comment: This will not guarantee that the numbers actually add up to 30. You could make the last number non-random so they add up to the right amount.. after all, they can't all be random. If that number is already in the array though, you have a small problem :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry i missed 'no duplicates' too
-so need to tack on a 'deduplicator' ...i put it in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794582/replace-duplicate-values-in-array-with-new-randomly-generated-values/2798726#2798726)

To generate a series of random numbers with a fixed sum:

- make a series of random numbers (of largest practical magnitude to hide granularity...)
- calculate their sum
- multiply each in series by desiredsum/sum

(basicaly to scale a random series to its new size)

Then there is rounding error to adjust for:

- recalculate sum and its difference
  from desired sum
- add the sumdiff to a random element
  in series if it doesnt result in a
  negative, if it does loop to another
  random element until fine.
- to be ultratight instead add or
  subtract 1 bit to random elements
  until sumdiff=0

Some non-randomness resulting from doing it like this is if the magnitude of the source randoms is too small causing granularity in the result.

I dont have php, but here's a shot -

```
$n = ;              //size of array
$targsum = ;        //target sum
$ceiling = 0x3fff;  //biggish number for rands
$sizedrands = array();

$firstsum=0;
$finsum=0;

//make rands, sum size
for( $count=$n; $count>0; $count--)
{ $arand=rand( 0, $ceiling );
  $sizedrands($count)=$arand;
  $firstsum+=$arand; }

//resize, sum resize
for( $count=$n; $count>0; $count--)
{ $sizedrands($count)=($sizedrands($count)*$targsum)/$firstsum;
  $finsum+=$sizedrands($count);
  }

//redistribute parts of rounding error randomly until done
$roundup=$targsum-$finsum;

$rounder=1; if($roundup<0){ $rounder=-1; }

while( $roundup!=0 )
{ $arand=rand( 0, $n );
  if( ($rounder+$sizedrands($arand) ) > 0 )
  { $sizedrands($arand)+=$rounder; 
    $roundup-=$rounder; }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you more....

Approch-1

```
$aRandomarray = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
{
    $iRandomValue = mt_rand(1000, 999);
    if (!in_array($iRandomValue , $aRandomarray)) {
        $aRandomarray[$i] = $iRandomValue;
    }
}
```

Approch-2

```
$aRandomarray = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
{
    $iRandomValue = mt_rand(100, 999);
    $sRandom .= $iRandomValue;
}
array_push($aRandomarray, $sRandom);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this creates n amount of numbers to add up to a specific amount?